# How does folder redirection remember the previous location of a folder?

Tags: windows, active-directory, folder-redirection

For example, I have a GPO that redirects the documents folder to `\\oldserver\username\My Documents` and the “Move the contents of Documents to the new location.” item is selected.

The user logs in and creates several files.

Then I change the GPO to point to `\\newserver\username\My Documents`

The next time the user logs in, the contents of his documents folder are moved from `\\oldserver\username\My Documents` to `\\newserver\username\My Documents`.

I’ve looked at the GPO object in SYSVOL, and it only contains the currently set location.

How did the computer remember the old location to move the files from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's stored in the client computer's registry.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/242557

Comment: That’s what I suspected. Does this mean that I will need to move files manually from old location to new location when mandatory profiles are in use?

Comment: That's actually a very good question that I do not know the answer to.